# Internal and External microphone isn't working

Tags: hardware

There is a problem with the microphone on my MacBook (Yosemite 10.10.3)

The internal speakers work OK, and if I plug in headphones, they will work too.
Unfortunately, the internal microphone doesn't work. When I plugged in an external microphone, it would't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas what could it be?

Comment: Could your internal microphone just be broken?

Answer (score 1):

I use a MacBook Pro, but I've noticed this behaviour with some software, where the audio gain in System Preferences gets reduced to zero (i.e., no mic input). I suggest the following procedure:

1. Launch the software that you're having difficuty with.
2. Go **System Preferences** >> **Sound** >> **Input**
3. Increase the **Input volume** slider as desired
4. Switch back to your software application, without closing the **System Preferences** dialog.

For some reason, if you close **System Preferences**, then this can cause the software to reassert zero gain.

You might also want to consider resetting the system, just to ensure that you're resetting anything that might be inadvertently causing your issue.